# Communicate with child process bidirectionally over STDIO

Tags: php, cmd, exec

I am trying to communicate with the Stockfish chess engine from a PHP script. For that I am using the [UCI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Chess_Interface), so I will need to send commands line by line. For example, this is what I would normally enter on the Windows Command Prompt:

```
Stockfish.exe
position startpos
go depth 16
```

Stockfish.exe is the 64-bit version of the [Stockfish chess engine](https://stockfishchess.org/download/).

I failed to do it using [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). Here is how I attempted it:

```
exec("stockfish.exe\nposition startpos\ngo depth 16");
```

The engine runs, but the commands are not executed, so I get:

> ```
> Stockfish 10 64 by T. Romstad, M. Costalba, J. Kiiski, G. Linscott
> ```

where I should get something like:

> ```
> info depth 1 seldepth 1 multipv 1 score cp 116 nodes 20 nps 10000 tbhits 0 time 2 pv e2e4  
> info depth 2 seldepth 2 multipv 1 score cp 112 nodes 54 nps 27000 tbhits 0 time 2 pv e2e4 b7b6  
> info depth 3 seldepth 3 multipv 1 score cp 148 nodes 136 nps 45333 tbhits 0 time 3 pv d2d4 d7d6 e2e4  
> info depth 4 seldepth 4 multipv 1 score cp 137 nodes 247 nps 61750 tbhits 0 time 4 pv d2d4 e7e6 e2e4 c7c6  
> bestmove d2d4 ponder e7e6
> ```

I've read [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446492/run-a-exe-with-input-parameters-from-php-web-page) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450169/sending-commands-to-windows-command-line-cmd-from-php) on related issues, but couldn't find a workaround. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just to clarify... you don't actually want to run a REPL in PHP (like the Windows command prompt), you want to send and receive line-delimited data for a child process (`stockfish.exe`) over STDIO, correct?

Comment: Yes, but what's a REPL?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop

Comment: Thanks. I am OK with both. What matters for me is getting the same output I would get if I were using the command prompt.

Comment: maybe this helps to execute the commands in one exec command, use && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122742/execute-two-shell-commands-in-single-exec-php-statement

Comment: @FatFreddy this doesn't work. I only get the text "Stockfish 10 64 by ...".

Comment: FWIW it seems to work correctly if the `position startpos` is left off. The following command returns the correct number of moves as expected `exec('stockfish.exe go depth 16' . "\r\n" . 'quit');`

Comment: It works because `startpos` is the default position, but sonner or later I will have to send something like `position startpos moves g1f3` followed by `go depth 16`, for instance.

Comment: And one thing to add: it only returns `bestmove e2e4 ponder e7e5` but omits the above lines.

Comment: When I ran it I got an array of 17 elements and the last one was the bestmove line. Had you included a variable in the call to exec?

Comment: I am not getting an array, only the above mentioned line (I am getting the same output with print_r instead of echo). And, I did not pass any variables in the call. I just did it the same way you did it.

Comment: Add `,$back);` after the 'quit' and you will see all of the moves.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188066/discussion-between-wais-kamal-and-dave).